# Find the optimal value of the argument for a given function value

Tags: python

I have a function- wait_time(agr1, arg2, arg3) and target for this function - target_waiting_time

How can I find the value of arg2 from this function for target_waiting_time = specific value?

Now I find it with a cycle, but it's too long.

```
arg1 = some_value1
arg2 = some_value2
arg3 = some_value3

#find waiting time
def wait_time(agr1, arg2, arg3):
      wait_prob = another_function(agr1, arg2, arg3)
      x = wait_prob / arg2/(arg3*(40))
      return x

target_waiting_time = 100

while wait_time < target_wait_time:
            arg2 += 1
            wait_time = wait_time(agr1, arg2, arg3)

optimal_value = arg2
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the minima of this function? https://www.mytutor.co.uk/answers/1663/A-Level/Maths/How-do-I-find-the-maxima-and-minima-of-a-function/

Comment: You can try to use a [bfgs optimiser](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs.html)

Comment: I have not tried it yet, thanks for the advice. But I was hoping that there is something already implemented in python.

Answer (score 0):

At the minute , you're incrementing `arg2` by 1 and trying again each time, and this is too slow. So, why not trying incrementing it by more at each step? Eg. by +5 or +10000 each time, then once you know eg. it's in the range 100-200 you can search that range using binary search.

In fact, a known pattern exists for this called https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search , but it may not be necessary for you depending on your needs and how large your values are going to be.

Answer (score 0):

I dicided it with scipy.optimize.fsolve

```
from scipy import optimize

arg1 = some_value1
arg2 = some_value2
arg3 = some_value3

#find waiting time
def wait_time(agr1, arg2, arg3):
    wait_prob = another_function(agr1, arg2, arg3)
    x = wait_prob / arg2/(arg3*(40))
    return x

target_waiting_time = 100

def func(x):
    return wait_time(agr1, x, arg3) - target_waiting_time 

optimal_value = optimize.fsolve(func, x0 = arg2)
```